# Setting up a on-demand modular git architecture

Tags: git

I have a rather large codebase (basically a framework with quite a few modules and layouts under it). Currently everything is in one git archive and it's starting to get too big to be practical (right now there's more than 2.5 GB of code in the repository which means that when I install/clone a website from git, I have about 2.5 GB of code when in reality about 40 or 50 MB would do; multiply this times 70 websites and you see that this is a huge waste of disk space).

As such, I'd like to reorganize things to use multiple git archives, my preferred approach would be the following:

```
Git #1: Framework Code
Git #2: Module #1
Git #3: Module #2
....
Git #15: Layout #1
Git #16: Layout #2
.....
etc.
```

The directory structure this has to finally end up in looks like this:

```
/                    -> Framework code
/module/<modName>    -> module code for each module
/layout/<layoutName> -> code for each layout
```

Can someone recommend a way of implementing such a beast so that I have multiple git repositories which I can pull into the source base on demand without confusing git.

I've looked at using git submodules and while they seem to be pretty close to what I want, they don't seem to support the "on-demand" inclusion of selective modules/layouts I need.

Thanks for an hints/ideas.

Comment: "*it's starting to get too big to be practical.*" Why do you say that?

Comment: Added explanation of why things are not practical anymore to question

Comment: If you have 2.5 GB of actual *code*, that is your problem. Instead I suspect it's mostly images, videos, pdfs, archives, and other hard to diff formats. There's numerous answers here about reducing your repository size with git-lfs.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to git-lfs. However, I'm still interesting in creating a git setup to allow me to realize my 'on-demand' module/layout build.

Comment: To that I would say that git is not a build, install, nor package dependency system. If you try to use it as one, its not going to work out well. The framework and modules should be individual repositories developed individually and released (that could just mean for internal use) as packages else they're not very *modular*. Any dependencies for the individual pieces should be pulled in via a dependency system.